# Logtalk : Load a file with camelcase naming on Windows

Tags: logtalk

With logtalk 3.1.2, under OS X and Linux, no problem to load a file with a camelcase name, but an exception is thrown on Windows (`ERROR : file does not exist`).

```
logtalk_load(mypath(myFileNameInCameCase))
```

What's wrong ?

Comment: That's odd. Can you update the post with the backend Prolog compiler name and version you're using so that I can try to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some backend Prolog compilers, such as SWI-Prolog when running on Windows, down-case file names when expanding file paths into absolute file paths. This caused a failure in the Logtalk compiler when going from the file argument in the compilation and loading predicates to an absolute file path and its components (directory, name, and extension). A workaround have been found and committed to the current git version. Thanks for the bug report.

Comment: Tested. Everything seems OK ! Thanks !